# MS Access - string to date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column Date with this format: `2019-07-01T07:03:05.612289+02:00`

And I need chage thit final form `yyyy-mm-ss` (in this example `2019-07-01`)

Unfortunately this code does nothing:

```
SELECT Format ([Date], "yyyy / mm / dd")
FROM table_1;
```

Thaks for tips

Comment: Data is stored in ms access table (as string) or in sql-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your scenario is straigh forward, you can try with `LEFT()` function:

```
SELECT LEFT([Date], 10)
FROM table_1;
```

to convert the same text value into the `yyyy-mm-dd` date format, use the `FORMAT()` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(LEFT([Date], 10), "yyyy-mm-dd")
FROM table_1;
```

Comment: but the result is text not date

Comment: The first expression will provide the desired result. The second only adds confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a combination of the [`left`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/left-function-d5897bf6-91f5-4bf8-853a-b63d7de09681) and [`cdate`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/type-conversion-functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202) functions to obtain a date value:

```
select cdate(left([date],10)) from table_1
```

And then apply any required formatting using the `Format` property of the field, so that the data remains stored as a date rather than a string.